# Recover VB Project Files

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

So today I was looking to zip a VS project up and send to a friend. I zipped it up, uploaded to Google Drive, and sent them a share. The trick is that I moved the entire project file out of VS rather than copying it. So now I have it all saved on my Google Drive, but I do not have a clue as to how to get it back in the VS projects folder. I thought I could just move it back into the VS 2013 Projects folder, but I was wrong. Sorry for the silly beginner question!

Comment: by project file, were you also able to include the solution file?

Comment: I do not see a .sln file in my folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need the solution file aswell, so that visual studio can open the whole project. Otherwise, you will only be able to open each item one by one.

[image]

My advice though, is taht in your projects folder you just zip the whole project instead to make sure that the solution file is also included.

[image]